# Is there any free ssl certificate that we can install for developing or SIT environments?

Tags: ssl

Anyone have any information on this?

Answer (score 6):

You can sign your own SSL certificate if it is what you mean. You can go [here](http://www.tc.umn.edu/~brams006/selfsign.html) for some advice on setting a self-signed certificate under linux, alternatively you can go [here](http://www.somacon.com/p42.php) for advices for IIS 6 based environments.

Answer (score 1):

You can create as many SSL certificates as you want with OpenSSL for example.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't care about proper trust-chain validation to a root Certificate Authority, you can use a self-signed cert.

MS has a makecert tool.

Answer (score 0):

http://cert.startcom.org/ provides free ssl certificates.

**Note:**
The "StartCom Certificate Policy & Practice Statements" document §3.1.2.1 is explicit that the Class 1 (free) certificates are for non-commercial uses only.[3] The previous version of the CPS did not include this restriction. [https://www.startssl.com/policy.pdf]

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use startssl.com with free in class 1. please check it http://blog.myee.web.id/get-free-ssl-for-your-site/ or http://www.myee.web.id/get-free-ssl-for-your-site/